# Execute commands coming from a serial port

Tags: bash, shell, serial-port

I have some hardware that is sending commands over /dev/ttyACM0 every once in a while and I'd like to execute them in a terminal. For example, if the ascii "ls" comes over /dev/ttyACM0, I'd like to have a terminal actually run that. Is there some command-line-fu I can use to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just run the following

```
sh /dev/ttyACM0
```

This will treat `/dev/ttyACM0` as a script and run anything that comes from it.

Comment: Are the results of the command in the terminal sent back to the Serial port. i.e, is it one way or two way terminal communication?

Comment: Bash treats it as a script. Meaning bash doesn't know that it's not a script. It see's a file that it can read commands from and so it does just that. If the /dev device supports it, you can just do a normal shell redirect to send the output into it.